# Searching Entrez based on paper title

Tags: python, biopython, ncbi, pubmed

I am trying to search NCBI's Entrez based on a title. Here are my GET requests's URL and parameters:

```py
import requests

url = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi"
# SEE: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8021862/
params = {
    "tool": "foo",
    "email": "example@example.com",
    "api_key": None,
    "retmode": "json",
    "db": "pubmed",
    "retmax": "1",
    "term": '"Interpreting Genetic Variation in Human and Cancer Genomes"[Title]',
}
response = requests.get(url, params=params, timeout=15.0)
response.raise_for_status()
result = response.json()["esearchresult"]
```

However, I am getting no results, the `result["count"]` is 0. How can I search Entrez for based on a paper's title?

When answering, feel free to use `requests` directly, or common Entrez wrappers like `biopython`'s [`Bio.Entrez`](https://biopython.org/docs/latest/api/Bio.Entrez.html) or [`easy-entrez`](https://github.com/krassowski/easy-entrez). I am using Python 3.11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, turns out nothing is ever easy.

TL;DR use [proximity search](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/help/#proximity-searching) with a distance of 0.

```
"term": '"Interpreting Genetic Variation in Human and Cancer Genomes"[Title:~0]'
```

---

Starting at the [PubMed User Guide](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/help/), in the "Searching for a phrase section", it talks about PubMed's [phrase index](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/help/#phrase-index). Let's start by seeing what the phrase index contains for this search.

Going to [PubMed Advanced Search Builder](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/advanced/), and hitting the "Show Index" button:

[image: screenshot of PubMed Advanced Search Builder's Show Index]

We observe that the search query was not in the phrase index. Now back in the "Searching for a phrase" section, we see:

> If you use quotes and the phrase is not found in the [phrase index](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/help/#phrase-index), the quotes are ignored and the terms are processed using automatic term mapping.

Okay, so it seems [automatic term mapping (ATM)](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/help/#automatic-term-mapping) is failing us as well. Let's keep reading in the "Quoted phrase not found" section:

> To search for a phrase that is not found in the phrase index, use a [proximity search](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/help/#proximity-searching) with a distance of 0 (...); this will search for the quoted terms appearing next to each other, in any order.

Now, trying that proximity search with 0 distance:

```py
import requests

url = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi"
# SEE: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8021862/
params = {
    "tool": "foo",
    "email": "example@example.com",
    "api_key": None,
    "retmode": "json",
    "db": "pubmed",
    "retmax": "1",
    "term": '"Interpreting Genetic Variation in Human and Cancer Genomes"[Title:~0]',
}
response = requests.get(url, params=params, timeout=15.0)
response.raise_for_status()
result = response.json()["esearchresult"]
print(result["count"])  # Prints: 1
print(result["idlist"][0])  # Prints: 33834021
```

It works! Case closed.

Notes:

1. Searching for a whole title in exact ordering (via double quotes) doesn't work, because the PubMed doesn't index full titles into the phrase index.
2. Using a zero distance proximity search has a downside: it doesn't enforce exact term ordering. However, it's a viable workaround for point 1.